# Spark cluster on Bluemix gets busy on running applications

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I have a problem running the application on Spark cluster on Bluemix Spark service. Sometimes the cluster gets busy and the application hangs and then fails by timeout and memory lack. The same happens on Spark notebooks when kernel becomes permanently busy in the service. Now I have to create a new Spark service and rerun my application within the new one. The problem is reproducible even on the simplest applications. It seems that service becomes available again after 48-72 hours of inactivity. Is any solution for solving the instability of Bluemix Spark Service?

Comment: Can you provide some example code and sizes of the data you have used ?
Providing the stack-traces of the Exceptions could also help.

Comment: Hi,

Can you check response from this thread and see if that helps?
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/277899/jupyter-notebook-kernel-permanently-busy.html
 Jul 17 at 06:51 PM

May be you need to free up some of hanging jobs first.

Thanks,
Charles.